# Create macro to validate cells and write error report to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that runs a loads of validations (there'll be a lot more than is currently in my code) on a data sheet/template we receive.

When it finds an issue the macro formats the fill of the cell to red and then it needs to write the issue to an error report in a new sheet.  The error report needs to write the row of the error in Col A and a brief description of the error in Col B.

I have got the below macro to half work in that it fills all the incorrect cells in red, but I can not get it to write to the error report correctly.

1) When I use Activecell.row it returns the row of active cell I was in before I ran the macro and not the row in the loop (iRow)

2) I cannot get it to write the errors underneath each other, it keeps overwriting even though I've tried using a lastARow parameter when I step through, it is not changing.  Not sure if there is something I'm missing or if I need another loop within a loop (I've tried this too)

```
Sub CheckValidations()

Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, ARow As Long, firstARow As Long, lastARow As Long



Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    lastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = 14

    lastARow = Sheets("Errors").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



        'For each row check validations in specific columns
    For iRow = lastRow To firstRow Step -1


        'Check SubFunction Exists, if not highlight cell and write issue to
 error report
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "CRO & Admin" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Operational Risk" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Global Risk Analytics" _
            And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Risk Strategy" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Security & Fraud Risk" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Wholesale & Market Risk" _
            And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "RBWM Risk" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Indirects" And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Run Risk Like a Business" _
            And Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "Location Optimisation" Then
                Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Row 'Activecell.row returns cell from before macro was initiated, not iRow
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 2).Value = "Value not in dropdown/allowed"
            End If

            'Check Proj Start date not before 01/07/2015, if it is wirte isue to error report
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 6) < DateSerial(2015, 7, 1) Then
                Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Row 'Activecell.row returns cell from before macro was initiated, not iRow
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 2).Value = "Start date before 01/07/2015"
            End If

            'Check Proj End date not after 31/12/2017, if it is wirte isue to error report
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 6) < DateSerial(2017, 12, 31) Then
                Sheets("Data").Cells(iRow, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Row 'Activecell.row returns cell from before macro was initiated, not iRow
                Sheets("Errors").Cells(lastARow, 2).Value = "Start date before 01/07/2015"
            End If

    Next iRow


Application.Calculation = x1Automatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think ActiveCell maybe referring to a sheet other than the one you think.  Try `Sheets("Error").Activate`, or whatever the sheet you think it should refer to.  Using assertions can be useful to test your assumptions, so you might try adding `Debug.Assert  ActiveSheet.name="Errors"` in the code which could help

Comment: Also, you should always explicitly tell what Sheet to use when using `Range()` (which you did), but also `Rows`,`Columns`...so your `lastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should be `lastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`  Not doing so can cause unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks this helped

Answer (score 0):

First, I personally don't like referring to active cells in the middle of vba code. I've had problems where I accidentally click on a sheet while a macro is running and it throws an error. Since you're already referring to `.Cells(iRow, #)` in your conditionals, why not use `.Cells(iRow, #).Row` instead?

Second, it seems like, from what your conditionals want to do, you're only recording one type of error, even if there's more than one for a given row. Is that your intent? If so, you may want to consider using Else If statements instead, so it only records the first error the macro comes across for row in the data sheet.

Third, your lastARow parameter isn't changing because you didn't tell the macro to change it. It's set before the for loop, then isn't touched. You likely want to increment lastARow each time it finds an error, after the error is written down. Use `lastARow = lastARow + 1`

Finally, you might notice an error in the last If conditional. I doubt you want to check if your project end date is before 2017 there.

Comment: Ah yes, I copied and pasted the conditions from before, meant to change to column 7 and >

Comment: Thanks @gualdhar  Almost there, one last thing, it's leaving varied amounts of blank rows inbetween the results in the error sheets, it seems the same amount of rows as the errors in the actual data sheet.  Any ideas how this could be corrected?